# Error when iterating over a character vector but omitting some elements

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I'm very new to R and am having some trouble when iterating through a character vector.

When iterating through a numeric vector, it is rather easy to omit one of the elements using the negation operator '-'. For example

```
for (i in (1:5)[-4]){
  print(i)
}
```

yields

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 5
```

However, applying the same method to a character vector raises an error

```
X = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
for (letter in (X)[-"d"]){
  print(letter)
}

Error in -"d" : invalid argument to unary operator
```

I have tried multiple variations on the above but all seem to return the same error. I was wondering if someone could tell me why these two cases are treated differently and what the correct syntax is?

Comment: `[-4]` doesn’t remove the value 4 from the vector. It removes the item *at index 4*. That’s why `[-"d"]` does not work: it doesn’t make sense to begin with.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for your response, I should have thought of it like this. I think I was getting the loop syntax confused with what you can do in dplyr where in some of the functionality you can negate a set of args in a vector using `-c(args)` and I simply tried to apply the same result here. Also, it turns out that using the set `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` to spot the problem was a bad choice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
setdiff(X, 'd')
```

or

```
X[-grep('d', X)]
```

Aside 1: many functions in R (like `print`) are *vectorised*, so they will digest all elements of a vector without explicitly being told to loop anyway.

Aside 2: R has more concise/readable/faster equivalents to loops in many cases: the whole `...apply` family, `Map`, `Reduce` (and their steroid variants from {[purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/)}) and such.

Try `letters[1:5] |> setdiff('d') |> paste('is not d')` to watch the pipe operator doing its magic, too :-)

Comment: Thanks for your response (+1). Yeah, I'm aware there are faster methods but right now I'm trying to understand the basic syntax of R which is why I'm specifically focussed on for loops. I will come back to your aside 2 in a couple of weeks.

Comment: AFAIK, loops got a bad reputation in R not because they slow things down as such, but because they're can seduce to "grow things" (e. g. by adding items to a list of previously undefined length) which then can really slow things down. More importantly, though, they kind of distract from the convenient feature of vectorised operations (perhaps comparable to missing out on Python's list comprehension).

Answer (score 1):

To use `-` in `[`, we need numeric indices. So we need to find out the position of "d" in `X` by using `which`.

```r
for (letter in X[-which(X == "d")]){
  print(letter)
}

[1] "a"
[1] "b"
[1] "c"
[1] "e"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response (+1). That answers part of my question. I suppose I was getting confused and assuming for loops worked in the same way as some of the functionality in dplyr, where you can use `-c(args)` in some contexts to omit args from specific operations.